# Imagick не может прочитать gif-изображение

Tags: php, изображения

Мне нужно обрезать часть анимированного gif-изображения. Для этого использую php + imagick:

```
$src = __DIR__ . '/0107.gif';

$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setFormat('gif');
$imagick->readImage($src);
$image = $imagick->coalesceImages();

$crop_w = 20;
$crop_h = 20;
$crop_y = 0;
$size_w = 20;
$size_h = 20;
foreach ($image as $frame) {
    $width = $frame->getImageWidth();
    $crop_x = $width - 20;
    $frame->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y);
    $frame->thumbnailImage($size_w, $size_h);
    $frame->setImagePage($size_w, $size_h, 0, 0);
}

$image = $image->deconstructImages();
$image->writeImages('test.gif', true);
```

Все изображения одного плана (height = 20px), домен + смайлик в конце. Мне нужно оставлять только смайлик. Некоторые gif imagick не может прочитать `$imagick->readImage($src)`:

[image: Gif-изображение загружается]  - ок (http://smiles.spb.su/editor-for-skype/skype-5.5/smiles-spb-su/0106.gif)

[image: Gif-изображение загружается]  - imagick fail (http://smiles.spb.su/editor-for-skype/skype-5.5/smiles-spb-su/0107.gif)

Возникает ошибка:

```
ImagickException thrown at [...] corrupt image `0107.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1356
```

После того, как я загрузил в вопрос две картинки для примера, затем скачал их отсюда - imagick уже смог их обе прочитать!
Вот если на [оригинале проверять](http://smiles.spb.su/editor-for-skype/skype-5.5/smiles-spb-su/0107.gif), то ошибка воспроизводится:

```
$imagick->readImageBlob(file_get_contents('http://smiles.spb.su/editor-for-skype/skype-5.5/smiles-spb-su/0107.gif'));
```

Comment: Проблема в закачке картинки. Посмотри что возвращает file_get_contents, добавь заголовки, которые представят тебя обычным браузером, а не роботом.

Comment: @norbornen картинка хорошо скачивается. Проблема в том, что для этой картинки не получается сделать `->readImage()`. При закачке сюда (на imgur.com) видимо какие то фильтры накладываются  на изображение, ведь с оригиналом картинки imagick не работает. Но, мне до сих пор не понятно как скриптом обрезать такие gif`ки.